# column is of type smallint but expression is of type boolean

Tags: mysql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

During MySQL to PostgreSQL db migration, few tables are getting called automatically from hibernate sequence next Val.

I am not able to find these hibernate sequence tables and  set Boolean field as numericboolean type for these tables which are getting called automatically from hibernate sequence.

I am getting error as  column is of type smallint but expression is of type boolean

I am trying to set Boolean field as numeric type using `@type` annotation but not able to find these tables which are getting called automatically from hibernate sequence next Val.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot find them exactly? How were they generated in the first place? Turn on SQL logging, look at the DDL generate from the persistence unit, or use a DB tool for Postgres (PgAdmin is nice) to see the tables within the schema.

Comment: Actually since I added hibernate sequence in db , from that time 2 insert queries are getting called automatically after every insert or update.  In this tables which are getting called automatically I have a Boolean feild which I need to convert them to smallint ,but i am not sure from where those tables getting called from spring boot service

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by two inserts automatically after every insert/update, or what you've done or mean with the "I added hibernate sequence in db". If you can see the SQL issued, you should be able to 'see' the sequence table used for sequencing, and I don't know why they would have a boolean field at all. Maybe show exactly what you are referring to - the error, how you are creating the tables etc.

Comment: @Chris , actually we are using hibernate envers in project for auditing , so when i do update operation  using  jpa , an insert to audit table happens internally . 
so in this audit table there are  int datatype columns which are not accepting boolean values coming from springboot.

I am not able to convert these to boolean to integer as these audit tables entity are not defined anywhere in my springboot proect.

Comment: Audit tables are initially based on your entity tables being audited, so I'm not sure what you are looking for or the problem here at all. How did these audit tables get created? Why would they have been created with a numeric type if you want a boolean, and what does that have to do with a sequence? Show the error and SQL statement. Best guess is you haven't told your context which database you are using so it is using types aimed at MySQL instead of Postgres.

Comment: Resolved this issue by changing bit datatype to bool in audit tables at db side postgre.